# trouble with React , restful DELETE

Tags: rest, react-redux

I'm using React-redux , Axios, restful JSON server and
I'm trying to delete a record on a JSON server using "DELETE"but every time i use this ACTION,it deletes all of the records on my JSON server instead of deleting certain record with the id.
any idea ?

```
deleteStream(id){
        return async (dispatch)=>{
            await axiosStream.delete(`/streams/${id}`)
            dispatch({type:DELETE_STREAM,payload:id})
            history.push("/stream/list")
        }
    }
```

is there something fundamentally wrong with my delete action?

Comment: looks like a problem with your api. Try using `curl` or something else to delete from api and see if that works correctly or not.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was with the JSON db server , it happened that I had several empty arrays,I just removed the unused ones.
though I'm still unclear how this worked out .